# Python Asyncio Producer Consumer Model Stops working

Tags: python, python-asyncio, producer-consumer

For two projects I rely on a asycio producer-consumer model to work through some tasks.
The producers work of messages that come in from either mqtt or zermq.

This is the code of interest (running python3.7):

```
async def Producer(client, topic_filter, queue):
    async with client.filtered_messages(topic_filter) as messages:
        async for message in messages:
            message = message.payload.decode()
            await queue.put(message)
            OutputText( 'Added element to queue.' ) 

async def Consumer(client, queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        item = await queue.get()
        await DoTask(client, item) 
        await asyncio.sleep(timedelay)
        queue.task_done()
```

When I just start up this code it works as expected. But after operating for time I find that the consumer stop working. When this happens I can still send messages to the script. The log file shows the print out that the element was added to the queue. But the consumer isn't triggered and remains idle.
I found that this normally happens when the machine that it is running on has to use some swap memory or goes to 100% CPU usage. Therefore I am guessing that the consumer doesn't have a proper connection with the queue anymore but I could be wrong.
Since I don't get any errors when this happens it is very hard to debug. Any idea's on how to debug this would be great.

Cheers,
Hilbert

Comment: Not sure if you've tried this, but limit the max size of the queue to a fraction of what it currently is to see if this is in fact a memory issue with the queue filling up too large. If it's a memory issue elsewhere in the code, try limiting memory use in those places as well just to check.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The size of the queue itself is not a problem (many 200 small entries at max.) Memory wise it was never the code itself that ran out of memory, but other tasks on the machine meant it was struggling from a memory perspective.